# Sharepoint products configuration wizard "cannot connect to master sql server"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am installing SharePoint 2013

I run the prerequisites executable and confirmed everything installed successfully.

I then ran the setup.exe and installed to a different (not the system) drive which also completed without errors

but I got this error when at the step to create the DB:

> "cannot connect to master sql server at "

I made sure windows firewall was off.

Comment: Usually SP is installed on the C:\  drive,  where MS have to create lot of folders,dlls , aspx files, webtemplate files, xml files,ascx controls, images, css, core js and a ton of  js files etc. So are you sure you want to install it on the some other drive ONLY?

Answer (score 1):

**This issue usually occurs in case of**

- The Database Server is not reachable from the SharePoint Application Server.
- The SQL Server port is closed and is not accessible from SharePoint Application Server.

> Please check, [How to Check SQL Server Instance Connectivity from the application server to database server for a specific user.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/28/check-sql-server-instance-connectivity/)

- SQL Server Service is stopped.
- SQL Agent is stopped.
- SQL Server Browser is stopped.
- SQL Server Network Configuration TCP/IP is disabled.
- SQL Server server was blocked by Firewall.

> Please check
>
> - [Can not connect to database master at SQL server in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/01/29/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server-at-servername-the-database-might-not-exist-or-the-current-user-does-not-have-permission-to-connect/)
> - [Unable to Start SQL Server Service](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/04/sql-server-service-is-not-running/)

- The provided account doesn’t have sufficient permission.

> Please, check [Can not connect to database master at SQL server in SharePoint](https://itcore.devoworx.net/cannot-connect-database-master-sql-server-sharepoint-configuration-wizard/)

Answer (score 0):

This error generally means that the account you’re using to configure SharePoint does not have adequate permissions to connect to the SQL Server computer and complete the configuration. Go back to the SQL Server computer and verify that your SharePoint administrator account had the correct server roles assigned, and that the master database existed. Please also verify that you had logged into the SharePoint Server computer with the SharePoint administrator account, so the configuration should have been able to continue.

If you still find the problem than please follow [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2011/01/06/troubleshooting-sharepoint-configuration-error-cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-server_name/).

Comment: but I had sharepoint install sql. Doesn't the prerequisite check install sql server for you? its all on the same server

Comment: actually prerequisites are few add-ons which will be installed on Windows. it will help to run SharePoint Installation wizard to run.

Comment: Oh I though it acutally install ms sql

Answer (score 0):

This also can be happened when you install SharePoint under the same box with sql but using different account then the one you used to install sql. It worked if you run configuration wizard under the same sql account used for installing sql.

This happened to me when installing SharePoint 2016 with SQL Server 2016 Developer edition.